# How do I understand ChatGPT's joke: 为什么音乐家总是迟到？因为他们总是在调音！?

Tags: meaning-in-context, humor

I asked ChatGPT (3.5 turbo) for some examples of 双关语 = "puns".  Among its examples is:

> 为什么音乐家总是迟到？因为他们总是在调音！
> Why are musicians always late?  Because they're always tuning.  [my translation]

I asked ChatGPT to explain the joke, and it said:

> 第三个笑话是一个双关语，利用了“调音”的多义性。在音乐领域，“调音”（tune）是指调整乐器的音高和音色，以使其与其他乐器和谐地演奏。而在日常生活中，“调音”也可以指“调整时间”，让钟表保持准确。因此，这个笑话的双关语是指音乐家总是在调整乐器的音高和音色，而非调整他们的时间，导致他们经常迟到。这种反差让人感到出人意料和有趣，是双关语的常见特点。

I understand 调音 literally means "to tune" (a musical instrument), but I don't get how 调音 relates to 调整时间 = "adjusting time".  It should be a pun of some kind, so maybe there's a Chinese word which sounds like 调音 and has a relevant meaning.

It's also possible this pun makes no sense at all.

**Question**: How do I understand ChatGPT's joke?

Comment: chat gpt officially google translates chinese from english, as it was never intended to be accurate in any language, and there was no purpose to have multiple languages programmed.  I think if there was ever a pun it would have been english prior to translation, but because puns are so context heavy I feel that it will definitely be chargpt's weak point compared to some other requests.

Answer (score 3):

### 前言

抱歉，我暫時不太懂得使用英語回答你的問題，但我能看懂你說的，所以我先暫時使用中文回答你的問題吧，請見諒。

我想你或者可以複製我整段的文字到另外一些翻譯軟件裏，例如說 chatgpt、Google Translator、deepl 等等，那麼你就懂得我在大致說甚麼了。

我主要作答的地區文字：中文繁體

---

### 正式回答

以我所知，在中國內地、香港或者台灣地區，並沒有出現過相關的梗。

而且以我看來，這個根本就是一個錯誤的笑話。就如你所說，這個就是個錯誤的雙關語。

我想之所以會出現這個錯誤，第一個原因很可能是因為 chatgpt 的訓練資料庫裏的中文材料太少了。

加上也有另一個重要的原因，在這裏恕我引用一篇來至內地的一篇分析文章——[内容平台的进化方向：我看中文互联网的“精品化”道路](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/gMj8YU2j8ngfKqtTqAP4KQ)。

以下是一小節我抄出來的重點：

> - 高度同质化，大家都在追热点、钻算法空子，无论是文字内容还是视频内容，看一条就等于看一千条，反正都差不多。
> - 信息密度低，到处是“震惊体”“废话体”，两三句话能说清的事情非要消耗用户五分钟的时间，看完了还是一头雾水。
> - 原创性弱，天下内容一大抄，抄完了中文抄英文，还不承认自己是抄的。
> - 客观性差，观点和事实不分，“开局一张图、内容全靠编”。

上面這個小節大致就是說到中國內地的互聯網上很多都充斥著垃圾內容，正所謂一句在英語世界裏很通行的話——「Rubbish in, rubbish out」。

總的來說，也就是這次應該是 chatgpt 出錯了，你不要介意。

Answer (score 2):

You actually asked two questions.

(1) On the joke of a musician. I do not think it makes any sense from the point of view of the Chinese language. The Chinese word 调音 has nothing to do with time. The Chinese words 调整时间 = 调表 = 对时间 have nothing to do with the pitches.

(2) Are there Chinese words that sound like 调音 and have a relevant meaning? Yes. For example,

他总是比别人慢**半拍**。(half of a beat)

做人还是要**低调**一些。(lower tone)

能力不足的人常常会唱**高调**。(high voice)

他的文章，既有**阳春白雪**，又有**下里巴人**。(classical symphony, folk music)

**曲高**和寡， 水清无鱼。(A highbrow song finds fewer singers in the chorus.)

Answer (score 2):

As a native speaker, I confirm that "调音" has nothing to do with "调整时间". This is just a ChatGPT error. It is not anything like a joke.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it means "**tune = adjust** sound/something to arrive at a correct pitch/timing".

为什么音乐家总是迟到？因为他们总是在调音(忽視了調節時間)！- Why are musicians always arrive late? Because they are always (highly focused) on adjusting the sound of their musical instruments (but their time/clock).